# Inserting data in to data base in php

Tags: php

Helo dear friends. Please i have a probleme while inserting data whic contains cotes (",') into my database. Insertion ends when the first " is found my string.

My query is

```
"INSERT INTO table(Id,message,Date) VALUES(1,"here is come text",?) "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

be sure to use single quotes

```
"INSERT INTO table (Id, message, Date) VALUES (1, 'here is come text', ?)"
```